# Python selenium how to get only paragraphs with text

Tags: python, selenium

Imagine I have such html:

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Sometext</p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p>More text</p>
  <p></p>
<div>
```

Using selenium, is there a way to get only paragraphs which contain text? In example it will be the first and the fourth paragraphs..

Comment: Its very unclear about what kind of output you expect, May be you can post the url and the expected output.

Comment: use this xpath //p[text()]

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to get node with not empty text,
`normalize-space()` removes whitespaces:

```
//p[normalize-space(.)!='']
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I want